# clickhouse with jsonArray

Tags: clickhouse, mybatis-plus

I use clickhouse to storage String data, the data is a jsonArray,how can I query data with the condition in the jsonArray？

```
select
    id, sku_id, total_amount, create_time
from
    t_stock
array join JSONExtractArrayRaw(sku_id) as json
where 
JSONExtractRaw(json, 'memberProvinceNo') in (18,19)
group BY (id, sku_id, total_amount, create_time)
```

I got this, but I cannot use mybatis-plus query it.